# Codeigniter log class not being called when running via CLI

Tags: codeigniter, command-line-interface, logging

I have enabled the inbuilt logging within Codeigniter. This works fine.

However I'm running a particular script through the command line interface, of which works fine, however none of the normal logs are being updated. If I call the script through http the logs update fine.

Is it some built in feature within CI that running through the CLI won't update the logs, or do I have a problem somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is normally a difference in the user that CI uses to write the logs.

If you are using the browser it may be using an Apache Web-User like ours does.

If you do it through the command line you are normally logged in as yourself.  Do you have write permissions to the log file?

Comment: Thanks you're right. When I log in as root and execute the script the logs update, but logged in as my user they don't. Obviously a permissions issue with my account.